# How do I make my program detect special characters, specifically " !@#$%^&* "?

Tags: java, string

I've never used "pattern" or anything as such. I also can't use methods that I haven't been taught in class. My teacher is hoping that we can write a code that can detect lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, symbols, and the length of the string. Here's my code, I don't want for my code to be completely solved, I just need to know how to do parts of my code.

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text;
    int passLength = 0, upperCase = 0, lowerCase = 0, digit = 0, symbol = 0, point = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    text = console.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))){ //Checks for uppercase letters
            upperCase++;
        } 
        if (Character.isLowerCase(text.charAt(i))){ //Checks for lowercase letters
            lowerCase++;
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i))){ //checks for digits
            digit++;
        }
```

Comment: I also am aware that it's nowhere near done, but I just need help on how to make my program detect symbols/special characters.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: I have my code programmed to detect for lowercase, uppercase letters, and digits, but I can't seem to find a way for my program to detect symbols. the others are easy because there's methods like "isUpperCase" and "isLowerCase", but they don't have really a method for symbols/special characters. Would you help me having my program detect symbols is what i'm asking.

Comment: `"!@#$%^&*".indexOf(text.charAt(i)) != -1`

Comment: Might want to add `else`s to the `if`s to find none-of-the-above character